# how to generate and append the ids/numeric value to the input id attribute in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I have table which is created dynamically i need to pass id attribute with numeric value to input tag so that i can retrieve the input filed value.
I used for Each tag to loop 
code snippet:

```
<c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
<tr>
    <td>${entry.key}</td> // first t d filed 
    <td><input id="${id}" type="text" value="${entry.value}" size="50" /></t d> // second t d field with value 
</tr>
</c:for Each>   

I need something like this :
<input id="2" type="text" value="value" size="50" />
how can do this?can someone suggest me.
```

Comment: Use a variable and increment it inside loop and assign it as id.

Comment: thanks Rahman can u please share some example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable and assign it to it as Tanjim said- 
Use it like this-

```
<c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry" varStatus="Status">
<tr>
<td>${entry.key}</td> // first t d filed 
  <td><input id="${Status.count}" type="text" value="${entry.value}" size="50" /></td>
 </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: thanks yash i resloved issue.
<c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry" varStatus="theCount">
      <tr>
       <td><font color="#6b96db"><b>${entry.key}</b></font></td>
       <td>
          <input id="${theCount.count}" type="text" value="${entry.value}" size="50" />
       </td>
      </tr>
     </c:forEach>